# How to fetch the last row data using .val() from a table and show it in alert using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();

    var markup = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
  });

  $(".bttn").click(function() {
    var i = $("#tab").find("tr").last().val();
    alert(i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter Parker</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
<button type="button" class="bttn">show Row</button>
```

I have a table in which it adds rows when "add row" button is clicked. Every time if I press "show row" button, the last row data should be shown in alert prompt. How to do that using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as `TR` element doesn't have `value` property.

```
$("#tab").find("tr").last().text()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-row").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();

    var markup = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
  });

  $(".bttn").click(function() {
    var i = $("#tab").find("tr").last().text().trim();
    alert(i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
</form>
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter Parker</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
<button type="button" class="bttn">show Row</button>
```

Comment: It is working, thanks. But how to do this if the table contains multiple columns and I want to display all the value in the last row?

Comment: @Darshantheerth, Existing code will work, You can also explore  `$("#tab").find("tr:last td:eq(0)").text()`

Answer (score 1):

with .val() you can't achieve this because .val() works with input field, and for getting innerHTML you have to use .text()

You can print any of row/column content using this

```
var value= $("#tab tr:eq(2) td:eq(4)").text();
alert(value)
```

and for last row use:

```
alert($('#tab tr:last').text());
```